# merging pandas df based on 'contains' to complete df

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 large pandas dfs, where the first one contains IDs where some are updated and others are not. I want to merge the dfs such that it will include the corresponding old/new ID as a comma separated list.

DF1:

```
ID         name 
nfi23     sally
arb128    joe
mbi13     mary
```

DF2

```
ID_old     ID_updated
nfi23        wjm348
hji21        arb128
mbi13        ybm328
```

desired:

```
ID                 name
nfi23, wjm348      sally
hji21, arb128      joe
mbi13, ybm328      mary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
#combine the old and updated id and create new column
df2['combined'] = df2['ID_old'] + "," + df2['ID_updated']

# melt, to flatten the DF
df3=df2.melt('combined', value_name='ID')

#finally, merge the DF and the melted DF2 (as DF3)
df4=df.merge(df3, 
        on='ID',
        how='left').drop(columns=['variable','ID'])
df4
```

OR make use the MAP

```
#combine the old and updated id and create new column
df2['combined'] = df2['ID_old'] + "," + df2['ID_updated']

# melt, to flatten the DF
df3=df2.melt('combined', value_name='ID')

#finally, use map in mapping the value
df['combined']=df['ID'].map(df3.set_index('ID')['combined'])
df.drop(columns='ID')
```

```
    name    combined
0   sally   nfi23,wjm348
1   joe     hji21,arb128
2   mary    mbi13,ybm328
```

Comment: nice use of `.melt()`!

Comment: Second method tells me: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: @youtube, if ID is not unique then mapping is not the solution. First method (merge) will function.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `ID_old` as an index in `df2` and then map it to `df1` while combining them:

```
mapper = df2.set_index("ID_old")["ID_updated"]
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'] + ", " + df1['ID'].map(mapper)
```

df1 Ouput:

```
     ID             name
0   nfi23, wjm348   sally
1   arb128, arb128  joe
2   mbi13, ybm328   mary
```

Comment: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: You can try `mapper = df2.drop_duplicates().set_index("ID_old")["ID_updated"]` ... but without your data I can't QC it. So make sure it is still giving you what you want.